# notifyItemChanged only working inside of the onBindViewHolder function and not inside of a different function inside of the RecycleViewAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I am relativley new to Android Studio and I have tried making a RecyclerView for my Application. I have ran into an issue where I cannot update the ViewHolder unless it's inside the ViewHolder itself.

Here is my RecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.testactivity

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView



class RecyclerViewAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var name : TextView
        var description : TextView
        var listCard : CardView


        init {
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projname)
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc)
            listCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.listCard)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.name.text = ideaList[position].name
        holder.description.text = ideaList[position].description
        holder.listCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ideaList[position].color))


        holder.itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linLayout).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            ideaList.remove(ideaList[position])
            println(position.toString())
            notifyItemChanged(ideaList.size)
        })

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ideaList.size
    }
    fun addItem(name: String, desc: String, color: String) {
        val idea = Idea(
            name,
            desc,
            color
        )
        ideaList.add(idea)
        notifyItemInserted(ideaList.size-1)
        println((ideaList.size-1).toString())

    }

}
```

And this is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //private var layoutManager: LayoutManager? = null
    //private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        lateinit var layoutManager : LayoutManager
        lateinit var adapter : RecyclerViewAdapter
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Switch Activity
        val accbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.accInf)

        accbtn.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            //i.putExtra("", value) **IMPORT THE ACCOUNT INFORMATION ONTO THIS PAGE

            this.startActivity(i)
            this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }

        // Add Item
        val addbtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.addBtn)
        val bottomSheet = BottomSheetFragment()

        // Use the add button to open a modal to add an item to a grid
        addbtn.setOnClickListener {
            //Open bottom sheet modal to add item
            bottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, "BottomSheetDialog")
        }

        // Add Item to Recycler view
        val recycleView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
        recycleView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        recycleView.adapter = adapter

    }
```

I have tried using it in the MainActivity and inside of the ViewAdapter, aswell when I did "notifyItemChanged(ideaList.size)" inside of the ViewHolder it worked, but it doesn't work with any of the notify functions outside of this.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does notifyOnItemChanged work anywhere, but the onBindViewHolder is the one place you should probably never call it-  the point of that function is to bind a view, preferably without side effects.  Luckily you aren't doing that, you're doing it in a callback set in that function which is totally different.

THe reason your call doesn't work is the call is wrong.  Your code is:

```
        ideaList.remove(ideaList[position])
        println(position.toString())
        notifyItemChanged(ideaList.size)
```

Let's say the size of the list is 10, and the position is 4 at the beginning of this function. First off, you didn't change anything-  you removed something.  Changed would be if you swapped the value at position X with a different value, but kept the size and placement unchanged.  So it should be notifyItemRemoved, not notifyItemChanged.  Secondly, the index you send is wrong-  you'd be sending 9 in my example above.  You should be sending 4, the index of the item removed.  So you want `notifyItemRemoved(position)`